# How to create a single dataframe from multiple csv files in a specified directory

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

The csv files are placed in a named folder by themselves. Would be useful to read all data from csv files into a single data frame. Here is some code so far:

```
#create a variable and look through contents of the directory 
files=[f for f in os.listdir("./your_directory") if f.endswith('.csv')]

#Initalize an empty data frame
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

#iterate through files and their contents, then concatenate their data into the data frame initialized above
for file in files:
   df = pd.read_csv('./your_directory' + file)
   all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df])

#Call the new data frame and verify that contents were transferred
all_data.head()
```

This gives error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 4-5: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

If someone gets this to work can you show a working example?

Comment: add encoding parameter ```df = pd.read_csv('./your_directory' + file,encoding="utf8")```

Comment: Did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it with all the code:

```
#create a variable and look through contents of the directory 
files=[f for f in os.listdir("./your_directory") if f.endswith('.csv')]

#Initalize an empty data frame
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

#iterate through files and their contents, then concatenate their data into the data frame initialized above
for file in files:
   df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob('./your_directory/*.csv)))
   all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df])

#Call the new data frame and verify that contents were transferred
all_data.head()
```